# Extension OverloadedString doesn't fully infer IsString. Why? Or what am I missing?

Tags: haskell

ghc 7.6.3

is quite upset for some code i'm trying to compile

the error is

```
No instance for (Data.String.IsString t3)
arising from the literal `"meh"'
The type variable `t3' is ambiguous
```

i don't understand. it's a literal. what is ambiguous? why can't it infer this as a string?

this is coming in a call like

```
foo bar "meh"
```

where `foo` doesn't require the second argument to be anything in particular (it must satisfy some `typeclass`, and it does for the particular combos it is getting.)

i'll note i can fix this error by changing the call to

```
foo bar ("meh" :: String)
```

which is clearly insane.

-- edit

maybe it has nothing to do with overloadedStrings

i can "reproduce" this error just with

```
data B a where
    Foo :: a -> B A
```

then in GHCi writing simply

```
Foo "ok"
```

(clearly this fails as i'm not deriving `Show`, but why do i also get

```
No instance for (Data.String.IsString a0)
    arising from the literal `"ok"'
  The type variable `a0' is ambiguous
  ...
```

? what's going on here? what does this mean?)

Comment: Because there is insufficient information to infer the type: `The type variable \`t3' is ambiguous`.  What you describe is a typical situation where the return type is polymorphic *and* the argument type is also polymorphic, so there's no way for GHC to figure out what type you actually want.

Comment: Can you reproduce your problem as a single source that shows it? Because you can see everything work here https://www.fpcomplete.com/user/k_bx/untitled

Answer (score 5):

> it's a literal. what is ambiguous? why can't it infer this as a string?

When you use `OverloadedStrings` "meh" is not a literal `String`.  It's a literal polymorphic value of type `IsString a => a`.  Its type can't be inferred as `String` because it could also be used as a lazy `ByteString`, strict `ByteString`, `Text`, etc..

> `foo` doesn't require the second argument to be anything in particular

If `foo` doesn't require the second argument to be anything in particular how does the type checker know the argument to `foo` should be a `String`, rather than a `Text`, etc.?

> i'll note i can fix this error by changing the call to `foo bar ("meh" :: String)` which is clearly insane.

Now you are telling the type checker which specific type you want for `"meh"`.

> maybe it has nothing to do with overloadedStrings

It is *exactly* to do with `OverloadedStrings`.  Personally I recommend not using `OverloadedStrings` and just using `Data.String.fromString` precisely because of the confusing behaviour you are seeing.

> i can "reproduce" this error just with ... what's going on here? what does this mean?

Here's a concrete example of the ambiguity.

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings, FlexibleInstances #-}

import Data.Text

class Foo a where
  foo :: a -> String

instance Foo String where
  foo _ = "String"

instance Foo Text where
  foo _ = "Text"

main :: IO ()
main = print (foo "meh")
```

What should `main` print?  It depends on the type of `"meh"`.  What type did the user want for `"meh"`?  With `OverloadedStrings` on, there's no way to know.

Comment: So why does it say that "IsString" can't be inferred? I'm not asking for "String" to be inferred ... ?

Comment: i agree in your example it's not clear what should happened.

what i'm confused about is:
  1) why not infer IsString for this litera?
  2) if not that, how to treat literals as "Strings" without explicit typing, via some extension?

Comment: `String` and `IsString` are different things.  It can't infer an `IsString` inference because it doesn't know what type of stringlike object should be used.  You can treat literal strings always as `String`s by just turning off `OverloadedString`s!